# how can i download and install twig 3?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am using twig 1.2 in my personal framework , after changing php version to 7 , I got an warning that twig-autoloader is deprecated. I want to use twig 3 instead but I cant find a source to download it. I am using PHP 7.3 with WAMP 3.2 but project do using on Linux host when finished.my questions are:

1. Where can I download twig 3?
2. How can I install it on PHP 7.2?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install [twig](https://packagist.org/packages/twig/twig) via composer.

```
composer require twig/twig
```

If you have twig already installed, via composer try

```
composer update
```

to update all packages or check the `composer.json` file and change the dependency manually. Afterwards run

```
composer install
```

Comment: thank for yor quick answer Markus . i don't know how composer works. where should i write this code?in OS cli or in PHP code and run it?where are the codes?

Comment: Please read about composer basics [getting started](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md). But for the short, you need to run it from CLI in the root of the project. It is quite easy, so you should get in quickly. When having an IDE like PHPStorm it is very intuitive, too.

Comment: hi dear Markus, thanks to your guidance twig 3 downloaded now in a folder behind older one.is it a way that i update older version , e.g copy twig v3 to older version and replace them. or it should update via command?

Comment: I am not sure, because composer adds an autoloader (projectroot/vendor directory) which the packages are all using. So at the start of your script you just require the autoloader and the classes are loaded when using their namespace.

Comment: thank you ,it worked and i downloaded twig 3 but i should find a way to use it in my project.